# Using for each within for each for terraform resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

My main.tf is like this, I wanted to assign "google_project_iam_binding" -> "members" with "instance-sink" -> "unique_writer_identity"
but I'm already using the for each to set the role in google_project_iam_binding but iam unable to think of a way to use for each twice to assign to members of unique_writer_identity.

```
resource "google_logging_project_bucket_config" "custom_log_bucket" {
    for_each        = var.cross_project_logsink_service
    bucket_id       = format("bkt-%s-%s-%s-%s-%s", local.monitored_resource_project[each.key])
    location        = "global"
    project         = var.monitoring_project
    retention_days  = 30
}


resource "google_logging_project_sink" "instance-sink" {
  for_each    = var.cross_project_logsink_service

  name        = format("%s_logsink_%s", var.domain, each.key)
  description = "log sink from ${local.monitored_resource_project[each.key]}"
  destination = "logging.googleapis.com/${google_logging_project_bucket_config.custom_log_bucket[0].id}"
  filter      = "resource.type=cloud_composer_environment"
  project     = local.monitored_resource_project[each.key] 
  unique_writer_identity = true
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "log-writer" {
  
  for_each = toset([
    "roles/storage.objectCreator",
    "roles/logging.bucketWriter"
  ])
  project = var.monitoring_project
  role = each.key

  members = [
    google_logging_project_sink.instance-sink.writer_identity #how to assign it to the above resource
  ]
}
```

Currently error looks like this

```
$ terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Missing resource instance key
│
│   on logsink.tf line 71, in resource "google_project_iam_binding" "log-writer":
│   71:     google_logging_project_sink.instance-sink.writer_identity
│
│ Because google_logging_project_sink.instance-sink has "for_each" set, its
│ attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
│
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     google_logging_project_sink.instance-sink[each.key]
```

The problem is I can't assign the above because it is using for_each of roles
tfvars looks like this

```
cross_project_logsink_service         = ["cloud_function"]
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: Added the error but the problem is I can't use [each.key] because it identifies the roles rather than  for_each    = var.cross_project_logsink_service

Comment: What exactly is `cross_project_logsink_service`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get values of individual instances of `google_logging_project_sink.instance-sink` using [values](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values):

```
 members = values(google_logging_project_sink.instance-sink)[*].writer_identity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "log-writer" {
 

  for_each = toset([
    "roles/storage.objectCreator",
    "roles/logging.bucketWriter"
  ])
  project = var.monitoring_project
  role = each.key

  members = [
    google_logging_project_sink.instance-sink[*].writer_identity
  ]
}
```